# Find the minimum distance between a fixed point and a curve.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $S$ be the distance between the point $(1,0)$ and any point $(x,y)$ on the curve $y=\sqrt x$.

(a) Find the coordinates $(x,y)$ of this point at which $S$ is a minimum.

(b) Given that $\frac {dx}{dt}=2\text{ cm s}^{-1}$, find $\frac {dS}{dt}$ where $x=1$.

I have tried to create an equation for the distance. So far I have:

$$S^2=\left(x-1 \right)^2 +y^2$$

$$S^2=x^2-2x+1 +y^2$$

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried to make a equation for the distance S square=X square-2X+1+Y square

Answer (score 0):

(a) You've made a good start.

You can first substitute $y=\sqrt x$ into your expression for $S^2$ to get:

$$S^2=x^2-2x+1 +x$$

$$S^2=x^2-x+1$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ (do you understand implicit differentiation?) gives:

$$2S \frac {dS}{dx}=2x-1$$

$S$ is minimised when $\frac {dS}{dx}=0$ which requires $2x-1=0$ or $x=\frac 12$.

I'll leave you to find the corresponding $y$-value.

(b) Starting with $x=1$ gives $S^2=1^2-1+1=1$, so $S=1$.

We can rearrange $2S \frac {dS}{dx}=2x-1$ as $\frac {dS}{dx}=\frac{2x-1}{2S}=\frac{2-1}{2}=\frac 12$

The chain rule says that $\frac {dS}{dt}=\frac {dS}{dx} \times \frac {dx}{dt} = \frac 12 \times 2 = 1$